# Implement vb .net chatlistview

Tags: vb.net, listview, social-networking

Hy, I'm programming a chat program in .net and I want to display chat messsage in a listview but I can't fix row height according to the message height i'm searching for a solution to implement a chat listview (like skype message listview or facebook message listview) if you have a solution please tell me thanks

Comment: Leave your row without height. it will auto adjust according to your message size. Please post some of your html code so that we can get clear picture of it

Comment: no it's not HTML it's VB .NET when I leave the row height an horizontal scrollbar appears, but I dont want the user to scroll horizontally I want that when text is too long its become multiline automatically and each row can have its own height according to the inside text

Comment: If you don't want to show horizontal scroll bar, add this style overflow-x:hidden; and also remove the height field too

Comment: I think you dont understand me, my project isn't in HTML is in VB .Net ... so I can't set this property; I'm asking for a way to implements chatlistview in .NET not in HTML